Belling IHT602 Induction Hob - wiring advice to single-phase with four cores?
I've bought a second-hand Belling IHT602 Induction Hob which has four cores...
Green/Yellow - Earth
Blue - Neutral
Two Lives - Brown and Black
I've installed a similar hob before (DIY, not an electrician) but the instructions were much more clear previously as it just said to put both lives into the single phase live-feed.  Whereas the instructions that I can find for this hob are not so clear?!
I'm assuming I won't need three-phase for this??   It's replacing another electric hob, so power is there, but only single-phase 230v in this UK apartment.
Can anybody make sense of how I connect this to my mains supply please?
Many thanks for any advice!





What voltage do you have available? That is required for an answer.

Ah, sorry, should have said, I'm in UK so voltage is 230v

Is this an expensive induction hob? Or a cheap one? My experience says that it's a bathtub curve - the least clear data sheet comes with the most expensive (and the least expensive) piece of equipment.

What size is the hob circuit's circuit breaker?

The label on the cable itself is somewhat unclear (unless you have two of three phases handy, which you don't.) Honestly looks like a printing error where it was probably supposed to have the 3-phase diagram on one side, and the single-phase on the other, but they printed the 3-phase on both sides.
The diagram at the bottom of the question is crystal-clear, that L1 & L2 both go to (a single) Line/Live and N1 joined to N2 (within the appliance) goes to Neutral when the supply is single-phase 220-240V

(Having thought about this again, my initial interpretation was probably wrong (see also Ecnerwal's comment), so I rewrote the answer.)
The diagrams are not very clear.But the one on the cable is for three-phase service (brown and black to separate phases). However, the 25 A rating seems suspect -- you don't need 25 A for 7 kW with two phases, and the wires look like 2.5 mm^2, so they should probably take only 16 A.
In the bottom diagram, the dashed line looks represents the appliance, where black and brown are connected to L1 and L2, and there is a bridge betwenen the two N terminals (is there actually one in the hob)? Both black and brown arethen connected to the single phase if you only have that.
The rating "220-240 V~ / 380-415 3N~" indicates that you can either take a single phase on two phases of a three-phase service.
Regarding the power: Possibly the hob measures the voltages and automatically adjusts the maximum power consumption so as not to trip the breaker.

The dashed line box is in the appliance. If it wasn't, the appliance would be short-circuiting 380-415 volts by joining L1 and L2 (that join is clearly illustrated) in your interpretation of the wiring diagram.

@Ecnerwal I see your point, though the power issue still confuses me. I have rephrased my answer.
